# Create A to Z subfolders from a main folder which comprises of thousands of files

Tags: file, batch-file, command-line, automation

**Main folder contents (example)**

```
apple.txt
art.txt
berry.txt
cherry.txt
coffee.txt
..,
...
...
zebra.txt
```

**Expected output (subfolders)**

```
A
  apple.txt
  art.txt
B
  berry.txt
C
  cherry.txt
  coffee.txt
...
...
...
Z
  zebra.txt
```

How can I accomplish this via Windows batch file?

Comment: Just test the first character and copy it to a matching directory if it matches it.. Hint: `%var:~0,1%`

Comment: Would you point me to a reference where I can learn more about `%var:~0,1%`? I do not even know what keywords to google...

Comment: A piece of a string is called a substring

Comment: I will add some references to the answer in a while.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a script I quickly wrote.
Basically create a `dir` if not exist, then search for all `.txt`files in the root of the script, then test the first letter of the word, then simply copy it to the matching directory.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%i in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do (
   if not exist %%i mkdir %%i
)
for %%f in (*.txt) do (
set "file=%%f"
set "var=!file:~0,1!"
echo move "%%~dpf!file!" "%%~dpf!var!\" 
)
pause
```

Once tested, simply remove the `echo` before `copy` in the second last line to actually perform the `copy` task

Comment: It should be noted that this script may result in empty folders if there happens to be no files with names beginning with the corresponding letter - but I don't consider that to necessarily be a problem.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Agreed, we can change it to test the chars first, then create the directories. but like we both agree, emtry dirs. are not a problem as such, unless required by OP.

Comment: probably `move` is closer to the askers intent than `copy`.

Comment: They won't be able to see the commands echoed without a pause or timeout. Would it not make more sense to just remove the upper `for` loop and move the `if not exist` line above the `move` as `If Not Exist "!var!\" MD "!var!"`? _(that would only create the folders necessary and additionally would do so for non-alphabetic characters too)_?

Comment: @compo as mentioned to jeff. I can do a character check then mkdir but it would create multple case directories unless you include a to upper case call. Numeric chars can be included but what is the limit? We can create `10file.txt` or `1000file.txt` so the OP has the basics, he can take it from here. :)

Comment: Thank you so much! @GerhardBarnard As you said, I will take it from here. :)

Answer (score 2):

Something like that can did the trick :

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%f in (*.txt) do (
    set "file=%%f"
    set "NewFolder=!file:~0,1!"
    If not exist "!NewFolder!" MD "!NewFolder!"
    echo Move "%%~dpf!file!" "%%~dpf!NewFolder!\" 
)
pause
```

Once tested, simply remove the `echo` command before `move`